# wordpress standalone php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress, and need to have a php file to do some non-wordpress logic.

If you try and navigate to it, wordpress thinks you are looking for a wp page, and does not find it, so responds with a 404.

Is there anyway to get workpress to allow access to a php page?
Maybe by changing the .htaccess file redirection rules?

Comment: by default the `-f` flag is so that the rewrite rule is not processed for files, post your .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Pu the file in the wp installation folder where you have the folders wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes. Then you can reach it using the yourWpSite/filename.php

You can also put it in your theme folder but then you have to reach it like this: yourWpSite/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/filename.php

Comment: what would be really perfect is if you could map a url like yourWpSite/filename to automatically go to yourWpSite/filename.php but if you do that, wordpress tries to look for a page named filename instead of a php page